# How can I set different Title Views for different pages in TabbedPage layout in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a main Navigation Page that is a Tabbed Page, linking different views.

I've set the  in the main Tabbed Page and it works, but I would like to set it different for each page.

This is the Tabbed Page:

```
<TabbedPage
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TestProiectLicenta.Views.UserPageForm" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProiectLicenta.Views"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
    xmlns:refresh="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh">

    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <local:CarsListPage Title="Cars" Icon="new_car_icon"/>
        <local:NewCarsListPage Title="New Cars" Icon="new_car_icon"/>

        <local:ChooseMethodFormPage Title="Add Car" Icon="new_add_icon" />
        <local:UserViewPage Title="New Page Test" Icon="new_user_icon" />
        <ContentPage Title="Settings" Icon="new_settings_icon.png">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="face_id" />
                        <Label Text="FaceID Login?" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Switch IsToggled="false" Toggled="Handle_Toggled" x:Name="Fid" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Sign Out" Clicked="SignOutButton" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

The views are Content Pages.

I would like to have a Title View for the first page with some controls, like search, delete etc. (it's a list of cars) and the user's picture, and the others with the title and maybe other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. Inside the TabbedPage, for each page that you need to have a special Navigation Bar you declare it like this:

```
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
```

Then you edit the new page and add the 
`<NavigationPage.TitleView/>`

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do is I set the `Title` property in every `ContentPage` and it reflects on to the page when I flip through tabs

```
<ContentPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle=""
         Title="My Demo Title">...
```

### Update:

In your TabbedPage, you can add the `NavigationPage's` `TitleView` something like below

```
 <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle=""
         Title="My Demo Title">
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="TitleImage"/>
    <Label x:Name="TitleLabel"/>
 </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Hope you can take care of the alignment and everything else.
So Now using the above names you will be able to access the title image and label whenever you please!!

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to have not only text, but the users image, and more that I can set from code.

Comment: Have you  tried using NavigationPage's TitleView API?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working in the separate tabbed pages. I try to set it and it does nothing. The only thing that works is the ToolbarItems but it's not enough for what I need.

Comment: Okay, are you using MVVM? Add can you add the `TitleView` code

Comment: I am not using MVVM

Comment: But this makes the TitleView appear for the tabbed page, and that means all the pages that it contains. I was wondering if I could make each page have a different title view

Comment: I do not think that would meet your scenario!